# Como criar os botões maximizar minimizar e fechar no tkinter (Python3)

Tags: python, tkinter

Gostaria de saber como criar os botões maximizar, minimizar e fechar no tkinter (Python). Apos ser retirado a barra de título, devem ser criados novos botões para personalizar a janela e deixar de forma diferente do padrão. Abaixo temos o código incompleto que estou criando no windows 7: (tudo que estiver dentro da função def tem que ter identação) obs: o programa começa no from tkinter import * e termina no janela.mainloop().

```
from tkinter import *

janela = Tk()

janela.title(" >>> Como criar os botão Maximizar? <<< ")

janela['bg'] = 'gray'

janela.wm_attributes('-fullscreen','true')

janela.geometry('340x400+500+200')

m = 0

def minimizar():

    janela.overrideredirect(False)

    janela.iconify()

    janela.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', 'True')

def fechar():

    janela.destroy()

def maximizar1():

    global m

    m = 0

    janela.overrideredirect(True)

    janela.geometry('1360x800+0+0')

def maximizar():

    global m

    m = 1

    janela.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', 'False')

    janela.overrideredirect(True)

    janela.geometry('340x300+500+200')

def maxi():

    print('1m=> ', m)

    if m == 0:

        maximizar()

    elif m == 1:

        maximizar1()

def move():

    pass


bt1 = Button(janela, text='Minimizar', font=("Helvetica", 14), bg='grey', command=minimizar)

bt1.grid(row=0, column=1)

bt2 = Button(janela, text='Maximizar', font=("Helvetica", 14), bg='grey', command=maxi)

bt2.grid(row=0, column=2)

bt3 = Button(janela, text='Sair', font=("Helvetica", 14), bg='grey', command=fechar)

bt3.grid(row=0, column=3)

janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: Para aprender como formatar a suas perguntas leia [Ajuda na edição do Markdown](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando apenas o `tkinter` eu não sei, mas você pode criar botões para manipular janelas utilizando a biblioteca `pygetwindow`. Veja esse exemplo abaixo:

```
from tkinter import Tk,Button
import pygetwindow

title = "Exemplo"

root = Tk()
root.title(title)
root.update() 
window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle(title)[0] # Obtém a janela através do título dela.

button = Button(root,width=15,text="Minimizar",command=window.minimize)
button.pack()
```

Para baixar essa biblioteca digite `pip install pygetwindow`. Espero ter lhe ajudado ;)

Comment: Vlw, vou dar uma olhada no pygetwindow. Obrigado.

Comment: Por nada kkk. Por acaso, eu descobri o pygetwindow algumas horas antes de te dar a resposta enquanto eu pesquisava sobre pyautogui xD